# How to load kml file into google map?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a kml file. I need to load this kml file into my site, which is finally shown as a Google Map using C# or Javascript. And I have this .kml file in my project's root directory.

Comment: what code are you using and what's your javascript look like..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the documentation link about Maps API v3 and KML layers:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/layers.html#KMLLayers

basically, you would do:

```
var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('<url of your KML file>');
layer.setMap(map);
```

Thanks

Comment: One more simple question: how do access the file which is on server folder.Currently my project is on local host so I am trying this way   C:\xxx\xxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\DemoSite\cta.kml              but it is not loading the file.And I want to give the condition so that it should work on my live site also without any changes to this path

Comment: you must use the server's path: http://localhost:9999/cta.kml or something like that... when you start your project (assuming Visual Studio with CTRL-F5), note the path of your browser. Good luck !